Programa en Python no acepta pasar el focus con enter
Hice un programa y no me acepta pasar el focus con enter, lo cual es molesto para el usuario estar usando el mouse o la tecla tab cada vez que pasa a otro campo.
Les dejo la parte del programa en que hago eso.
Leí que era por los grid que tenían que estar en otra línea, no en la del entry: lo hice así y nada; cambié todo a place y nada.
Con grid:
def val_ent(event,e1,e2):
    try:
        num = e1.get()
        num = (int(num)) 
        e2.focus_set
              
    except KeyError as error:
        e1=set()
        e1.focus_set
            

def val_dec(event,e1,e2):
    try:
        num = (int(e1)) 
        e2.focus_set
              
    except KeyError as error:
        e1=set()
        e1.focus_set
        
        
for i in range(18):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(6):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    
    
l1 = ctk.CTkLabel(root,text="Codigo", width=25,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorlabel,text_color=colorletra,anchor=W).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="WESN",padx=5,pady=1)
e1 = ctk.CTkEntry(root, textvariable=Vid, width=5,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorentry,text_color=colorletra)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="WESN",padx=5,pady=1)
e1.focus_set()
e1.bind("<Return>",lambda evento: val_ent(evento, e1,e2))

Con place:
def val_ent(event,e1,e2):
    try:
        num = e1.get()
        num = (int(num)) 
        e2.focus_set
              
    except KeyError as error:
        e1=set()
        e1.focus_set
            

def val_dec(event,e1,e2):
    try:
        num = (int(e1)) 
        e2.focus_set
              
    except KeyError as error:
        e1=set()
        e1.focus_set
        
        
for i in range(18):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(6):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    
    
l1 = ctk.CTkLabel(root,text="Codigo", width=230,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorlabel,text_color=colorletra,corner_radius=7,anchor=W).place(x=60, y=10)#.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="WESN",padx=5,pady=1)
e1 = ctk.CTkEntry(root, textvariable=Vid, width=65,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorentry,text_color=colorletra,corner_radius=7)
e1.place(x=300, y=10)#.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="WESN",padx=5,pady=1)
e1.focus_force()
e1.bind("<Return>",lambda evento: val_ent(evento, e1,e2))```


El error principal es que no estás llamando al método focus_set, en vez de:
e2.focus_set

debe ser
e2.focus_set()

Pero tu código ni siquera llega ahí. El código que tienes bajo el try no generá un KeyError, en todo caso un ValueError por el intento de conversion a int de algo que no lo sea.
Por otro lado, no se muy bien que pretendes con e1=set(), si no has ensombrecido el builtin set con una función propia que no muestras. set es el tipo/constructor para los conjuntos en Python, un contenedor para datos únicos y no ordenados basados en tablas hash. Al reasignar a e1 la salida de set éste ya no hara referencia al entry y e1.focus_set generará una excepción.
Si por casualidad solo quisieras validar la entrada y pasar al siguiente entry al pulsar Enter si la entrada es válida, sería algo así:
import customtkinter as ctk


def val_ent(event, e1, e2):
    num = e1.get()
    try:
        num = int(num) 
    except ValueError:
        # Hacer algo cuando la entrada no es válida
        pass
    else:
        e2.focus_set()
        

root = ctk.CTk()

colorentry = "Purple"
colorlabel= "Teal"
colorletra= "white"
vid = ctk.StringVar()
        
for i in range(18):
    root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
for i in range(6):
    root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    
    
ctk.CTkLabel(
    root, text="Codigo", width=25, font=("arial", 18),
    fg_color=colorlabel, text_color=colorletra, anchor="w"
).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="WESN", padx=5, pady=1)

e1 = ctk.CTkEntry(
    root, textvariable=vid, width=5, font=("arial", 18),
    fg_color=colorentry, text_color=colorletra
)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="WESN", padx=5, pady=1)
e1.focus_set()
e1.bind("<Return>", lambda evento: val_ent(evento, e1, e2))

ctk.CTkLabel(
    root, text="Dirección", width=25, font=("arial", 18),
    fg_color=colorlabel, text_color=colorletra, anchor="w"
).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="WESN", padx=5, pady=1)

e2 = ctk.CTkEntry(
    root, width=5, font=("arial", 18),
    fg_color=colorentry, text_color=colorletra
)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="WESN", padx=5, pady=1)

root.mainloop()

Dado que estás estableciendo el foco explícitamente, que uses place o grid es irrelevante.


tambien lo habia puesto asi pero tampoco funciona ya no se quemas buscarme dice que no es atributo dl objeto "  File "d:\GERARDO\pre_sistema_ult\Cli001_gra copy.py", line 347, in val_ent
e2.focus_set()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'focus_set'

Si sigues haciendo lo que que comento como segundo error o algo similar, lo de e1=set(), ese es precisamente el error que tendrás. Mi ejemplo es totalmente reprodcuible y deberia funcinarte sin problemas. Si aún así tienes problemas al adaptarlo puedes actualizar la pregunta (dejando lo que ahora tiene para no perder el contexto) agregando tu código actual.

@GerardoMendivil otro error tipico es hacer algo como e2 = ctk.CTkEntry(...).grid(...), pero en el código que muestras con e1 no lo haces así que supongo que no será el problema. El error solo nos dice que e2 es None y no una instancia de CTkEntry, en algún momento estás asignando None a la variable. Si no logras dar con el problema edita la pregunta como comentaba y vemos a ver que puede estar pasando.

el problema es que no funciona el pasar el foco, aqui lo hago directo para el primer entry y tampoco lo hace mira, l1 = ctk.CTkLabel(root,text="Codigo", width=230,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorlabel,text_color=colorletra,corner_radius=7,anchor=W)
l1.place(x=60, y=10)
e1 = ctk.CTkEntry(root, textvariable=Vid, width=65,font=("arial",18),fg_color=colorentry,text_color=colorletra,corner_radius=7)
e1.place(x=300, y=10)
e1.pack()
e1.focus_set()

hola FJSevilla de verdad agradecido y disculpa por hacerte perder tu tiempo ya logre darle focus al primer entry poniendo "root.update", no hacia el focus porque no se mostraba aun el widtget lo lei en una publicacion de aqui mismo stackoverflow pero no me funciona para el segundo entry voy a seguir intentanado, pero ya uno siente una satisfaccion espero cundo domine bien el lenguaje poder ayudar a quien lo necesite tambien

No te preocupes, no es molestia, para eso estamos aquí. Puede ser necesario como comentas  tener que  llamar a update() en algunos casos cuando se llama focus_set() antes de que el widget esté visible (antes de ejecutar el mainloop). Pero en el caso de una callback como la que planteas con el widget ya visible y con el mainloop en funcionamiento esto no solucionará el problema (el propio mainloop ya realiza la función de update aparte de otras cosa). Algo más debe estar pasando.

Si te aconsejo no compartir código más allá de una línea en comentarios, se pierde toda la indentación y es un lío. No tengas problemas en editar la pregunta, si no es una nueva pregunta, sino simplemente una actualización o un intento de aplicar lo sugerido en alguna respuesta, es correcto hacerlo. Simplemente, no elimines lo que ya hay y agrega al final tus avances y nuevos errores problemas

LIisto FJSevilla, finalmente se pudo solucionar de esta manera ,gracias por tu atencion,
try:
num = int(num)
except ValueError:
# Hacer algo cuando la entrada no es válida
messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","datos no validos, Intente otra vez")
Vid.set("")
else:
root.update
e2.focus_set()
